# Android Capturing OnFocusChange or Recents launched while on Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an Alert Dialog that I show called 'dialog' but onFocusChange does not get called when I press the recents button. Is there any way to catch when the recents button is called when there is an alert dialog up?

```
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();  

        enterPin.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {

                    Log.w("com.app", "focus");

                }
                else
                {
                    Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                    sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
                    Log.w("com.app", "closeDialog");

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Update: Was able to capture by using onPause and a Binded service.